# Can a Free Action be taken between Aiming and Attacking without losing the benefits of aiming?

Tags: actions, dark-heresy-2e

Aiming as a half or full action grants a bonus to the next attack made, and:

> The next action the Aiming character performs must be an attack
>   (Standard Attack, Semi-Auto Burst, Lightning Attack, and so on) or the
>   benefits of Aiming are lost.

If this character takes a free action, and then attacks (as a half or full action), is the bonus from the Aim action lost?

Answer (score 2):

### Rules as written are silent, thus it rests up to the Game Master.

**Aim**

> The active character takes extra time to make a more precise attack.
>   Aiming as a Half Action grants a +10 bonus to the character’s
>   Weapon Skill or Ballistic Skill test for his next attack, while aiming
>   as a Full Action grants a +20 bonus to the character’s next attack. The next action the Aiming character performs must be an attack
>   (Standard Attack, Semi-Auto Burst, Lightning Attack, and so on)
>   or the benefits of Aiming are lost. Aiming benefits are also lost
>   if the character performs a Reaction before making his attack.
>   Aiming can be used with both melee and ranged attacks, but not
>   with attacks made with psychic powers.

This could be interpret as "if you do anything that would cause an interruption or make you stop aiming, you loose your aiming bonus".

**Free action**

> Free Actions take only a moment to complete and usually require
>   no real effort. A character can perform Free Actions in addition to
>   any other actions on his turn.

In most cases you should be able to perform a free action before shooting and keep the bonus, however there might be situations, when you won't be allowed to.

Comment: I nominally agree with your implementation but not your interpretation. A Free Action is still an Action, so if you Half Action or Full Action Aim, if your next Action is a Free Action, you technically wasted the Aim.

However, that's stupid. A Free Action is, by definition, something that "take[s] only a moment to complete and usually require[s] no real effort."

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would not be looking to the wording of free action but rather that of aiming. Remember unless your DM is gracious (giving you something you don't deserve) the wording says your next action MUST be your attack. Meaning you can't take aim. Take your 5ft step and fire. You must fire...then take your free action. Or take you're free action, take aim, then fire. The aiming and firing must be joined.